# Comparing excel spreadsheet to mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

What algorithm should be used? If I have an excel spreadsheet and the fields are the same with mysql database and I want to compare them by uploading the excel spreadsheet and it will update to be correct if those fields are the same and alert which are incorrect.

It would be great if you guys could provide a working code to do this work.

Thanks!

Somvannda

Comment: So you only want to compare field names?

Comment: yeah compare the value by the field name, if the value are the same, then lets update the status and inform back if the value is incorrect.

Comment: Add another column in your sheet and compare it and write alerts in that column and download that file. You will get all alerts in your sheet it self.